# TypeError during compilation of extensions in GRASS GIS using g.extension

Tags: python, grass-gis, grass-7.4

I am using GRASS 7.4.0 on Ubuntu 18.04. I installed grass-dev using `sudo apt-get install grass-dev`, and then used `g.extension v.centerpoint` to try to install `v.centerpoint`. The output is below:

```
$g.extension v.centerpoint
WARNING: GRASS_ADDON_BASE is not defined, installing to ~/.grass7/addons
Fetching <v.centerpoint> from GRASS GIS Addons repository (be patient)...
Compiling...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/grass74/tools/mkhtml.py", line 229, in <module>
    name = re.search('(<!-- meta page name:)(.*)(-->)', src_data, re.IGNORECASE)
  File "/home/charlie/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 183, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
make: *** [/tmp/tmpTcbCB_/v.centerpoint/docs/html/v.centerpoint.html] Error 1
ERROR: Compilation failed, sorry. Please check above error messages.
```

I find the same `TypeError` when trying to install other extensions (e.g., `v.profile`). Is there a way to get around this `TypeError` to allow extensions to be installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Python 2 with GRASS GIS 7.4, then it works as expected:

```
GRASS 7.4.2svn (nc_spm_08_grass7):~ > g.extension v.centerpoint
Fetching <v.centerpoint> from GRASS GIS Addons repository (be patient)...
Compiling...
Installing...
Updating addons metadata file...
Installation of <v.centerpoint> successfully finished

# see how "python" is defined (here: my Fedora box)
GRASS 7.4.2svn (nc_spm_08_grass7):~ > which python
/usr/bin/python
GRASS 7.4.2svn (nc_spm_08_grass7):~ > ls -la /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Oct 15 17:24 /usr/bin/python -> python2
```

Yes, we are working on a new GRASS GIS release which is Python 3 based (already available as GRASS GIS 7.7 development version, just not yet published officially as "stable").